# Best way to trigger events from incoming SES email

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-sns, amazon-ses

I want to trigger some events based on the body of incoming emails.  I see at least two ways of doing this with SES and Lambda, and I'm wondering about the pros and cons.

1. SES triggers Lambda function.  Since SES is only available in a few regions, this means the Lambda function must also be in one of those regions.  This passes a JSON object to Lambda containing the headers but not the email content.
2. SES publishes to SNS, and Lambda function subscribes to the SNS topic.  The SNS topic must be in the same region as SES, but the Lambda function can be anywhere.  This way the Lambda function receives the full email content, up to maximum size of 150KB.
3. SES puts the message into S3 bucket, then S3 triggers Lambda.  Bucket must be in the same region.  This seems overly complex and might take longer because there is an extra call to get the S3 object.  There is some potential for error if another user puts objects into the same bucket.  This way you can use emails up to 10MB.

Are there any other options or have I gotten anything wrong?

Comment: Another option would be to use SQS between SNS and Lambda in case Lambdanhas trouble processing the first time

Answer (score 0):

I have gone the SES -> S3 bucket route. I have an S3 event that fires a lambda on create. The lambda then reads the email and moves it to another bucket with a ${emailAddress}/${emailSubject} format as the key and then deletes the original. This allows me to programmatically pull the body based on the email address and subject combination (which is known) in some of my automated tests. Usually, this occurs well within a second. (Today it seems to be running really slow... searching to figure out why which lead me here)